# Deduct if the menu is open in react-select DropdownIndicator handler

Tags: javascript, react-select

I'd need to change the style of the arrow  in `react-select`. I learned it can be done by using the `components` prop like in the code sample below.

However, the props coming to `DropdownIndicator` do not seem to provide any information if the menu is opened. I would need to use that information to change the arrow style depending on whether the menu is open or closed.

How could I get that information?

```
import ReactSelect, { components } from 'react-select';

...

const DropdownIndicator = (props) => {  
  const { isFocused } = props;
  
  // Which prop tells if the menu is open? Certainly isFocused is not the correct one.
  const caretClass = isFocused ? 'caret-up' : 'caret-down';

  return (
    <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
      <div className={`${caretClass}`} />
    </components.DropdownIndicator>
  );
};

return (<ReactSelect
 components={{ DropdownIndicator }}
 placeholder={placeholder}
 value={value}
 onBlur={onBlur}
 name={name}
 ...
/>)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `react-select` is passing all selectProps in custom components. And there is field called `menuIsOpen` in selectProps which is used to determine whether dropdown is open or not.

So you can access `menuIsOpen` by following:-

```
const DropdownIndicator = (props) => {  
  const { menuIsOpen } = props.selectProps;
  
  // menuIsOpen will tell if dropdown is open or not
  const caretClass = menuIsOpen ? 'caret-up' : 'caret-down';

  return (
    <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
      <div className={`${caretClass}`} />
    </components.DropdownIndicator>
  );
};
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. There it indeed is, under `selectProps`.